# Several symbols not found when running torify

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

I run the following in ubuntu and bash. What do the missing symbols mean? Is it necessary to solve the problem? How shall I solve the problem? Thanks.

```
$ torify myprogram
22:12:35 libtorsocks(19139): WARNING: The symbol res_query() was not found in any shared library with the reported error: Not Found!
  Also, we failed to find the symbol __res_query() with the reported error: Not Found
22:12:35 libtorsocks(19139): WARNING: The symbol res_search() was not found in any shared library with the reported error: Not Found!
  Also, we failed to find the symbol __res_search() with the reported error: Not Found
22:12:35 libtorsocks(19139): WARNING: The symbol res_send() was not found in any shared library with the reported error: Not Found!
  Also, we failed to find the symbol __res_send() with the reported error: Not Found
22:12:35 libtorsocks(19139): WARNING: The symbol res_querydomain() was not found in any shared library with the reported error: Not Found!
  Also, we failed to find the symbol __res_querydomain() with the reported error: Not Found
22:12:35 libtorsocks(19140): WARNING: The symbol res_query() was not found in any shared library with the reported error: Not Found!
  Also, we failed to find the symbol __res_query() with the reported error: Not Found
22:12:35 libtorsocks(19140): WARNING: The symbol res_search() was not found in any shared library with the reported error: Not Found!
  Also, we failed to find the symbol __res_search() with the reported error: Not Found
22:12:35 libtorsocks(19140): WARNING: The symbol res_send() was not found in any shared library with the reported error: Not Found!
  Also, we failed to find the symbol __res_send() with the reported error: Not Found
22:12:35 libtorsocks(19140): WARNING: The symbol res_querydomain() was not found in any shared library with the reported error: Not Found!
  Also, we failed to find the symbol __res_querydomain() with the reported error: Not Found
22:12:35 libtorsocks(19137): WARNING: The symbol res_query() was not found in any shared library with the reported error: Not Found!
  Also, we failed to find the symbol __res_query() with the reported error: Not Found
22:12:35 libtorsocks(19137): WARNING: The symbol res_search() was not found in any shared library with the reported error: Not Found!
  Also, we failed to find the symbol __res_search() with the reported error: Not Found
22:12:35 libtorsocks(19137): WARNING: The symbol res_send() was not found in any shared library with the reported error: Not Found!
  Also, we failed to find the symbol __res_send() with the reported error: Not Found
22:12:35 libtorsocks(19137): WARNING: The symbol res_querydomain() was not found in any shared library with the reported error: Not Found!
  Also, we failed to find the symbol __res_querydomain() with the reported error: Not Found
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS. It works fine on my Raspberry Pi running the same Tor version.

Comment: Agreed - I can reproduce this too. A quick Google of "torify res_query" shows lots of past results, which suggests issues of this type are known about. Does your program actually work, regardless of the warnings?

Comment: try this: torify yourcomand 2>/dev/null